# Page.ResolveUrl() not working on VS2010 Dev Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to use an existing, old, ASP.Net web application that will serve as the main UI for our project. The web application employs MANY user controls, with a lot of:

```
<element attribute='<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/path/to/resource")' ...
```

I have a problem, however. If the application is deployed to IIS, these calls to Page.ResolveUrl() work fine. But if I try to run this application in Visual Studio Development Server, it does not resolve any URLs (i.e., no styles applied, no images rendered, etc.)

```
// If deployed in IIS, the style tag renders like this (and works):
<link href="/adminconsole/styles/styles.css" ...

// On the VS Dev Server:
<link href="/styles/styles.css" ...
```

What I want, is for these calls to "just work" no matter if the application is deployed to IIS, or is running on the Visual Studio Development Server.

**Some pertinent info:**

The web app does not use a master page. It includes the header as a user control :(

Comment: When you say they do not work can you explain what they do instead.  A good idea would be to compare the output of ResolveUrl on the dev server and on IIS for a given resource.

Comment: @Ben -In IIS: styles applied, images rendered. VS Dev Server: no styles applied, no images rendered. I thought it was pretty clear in my post above...

Comment: No that is very unclear, there are many reasons that a style may not be applied, what is the VALUE output by the method, i.e. in your example of `<element attribute='<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/path/to/resource")' ` what value is the attribute set to in iis versus what is the value set in the dev server.

Comment: The stylesheet, for instance, if deployed to IIS renders like this: <link href="/adminconsole/styles/styles.css" ... />, on the VS Dev Server, like this: <link href="/styles/styles.css" ... /> (I've added this info to the OP)

Comment: How is your application deployed in IIS?  I'm assuming that it is under the virtual directory adminconsole, but is it configured as its own application?  It would seem like to me that "~/path/to/resource" should resolve as "/path/to/resource" regardless of what virtual directory you are in, where "/" is the root of the application, not necessarily the root of the web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VS Dev web server is usually having only one site and accessing on localhost with a certain port number. Check project properties in web tab and see if you can change that Url to have a site name like you have in IIS. If not possible and if you are not willing to change the code make your developers to use local IIS or IIS express instead of that little VS toy.

In my experience is anyway much better to develop and test on IIS because you work in a more similar to production environment and if any, you discover issues earlier so have more time to react not last night before go live.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something like this very recently but instead of using `<%=ResolveURL("~/path/to/file")%>` I used `<%=ResolveURL("relative/path/to/file")%>` try that to see if that works. It worked for me.

I also think that testing/debugging on local IIS is definitely better. Remember, Cassini (the toy web server that ships with VS) runs under the developer's credentials so permissions to the local file system are very different compared to running your website on IIS directly.

Comment: this would probably break if the app is installed in a different way in the future or at present time on a web server where the app is available at: http://domain/site1/App ... urls should never be hardcoded as in IIS you can configure the app as web site top level or in any unpredictable level of folder nesting...

Comment: I am not suggesting hard coding anything. ResolveUrl accepts relative paths. In fact, if you specify an absolute path ResolveUrl will return it untouched. I fail to see how a relative path, as I suggested, will break under a different virtual directory.